# Does any one know what's wrong in this program?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

This program should make insertion, deletion for a binary tree node.
The problem is when i display the tree elements after making a deletion, the program shows an error. Please, help whats wrong in my program.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

class Tnode
{
public:
    class Tnode *left;
    class Tnode *right;
    int info;
};

class tree: public Tnode
{
public:
    int top;
    Tnode *root;

    tree()
    {
        root=NULL;
        top=0;
    }

    void insert(int ch)
    {
        Tnode *temp,*temp1;
        if(root== NULL)
        {
            root=new Tnode;
            root->info=ch;
            root->left=NULL;
            root->right=NULL;
            return;
        }
        temp1=new Tnode;
        temp1->info=ch;
        temp1->right=temp1->left=NULL;
        temp=search(root,ch);
        if(temp->info>ch)
            temp->left=temp1;
        else
            temp->right=temp1;
    }

    Tnode *search(Tnode *temp,int ch)
    {
        if(root== NULL)
        {
            cout <<"no node present";
            return NULL;
        }
        if(temp->left==NULL && temp->right== NULL)
            return temp;

        if(temp->info>ch)
        {
            if(temp->left==NULL) return temp;
            search(temp->left,ch);
        }
        else
        { 
            if(temp->right==NULL) return temp;
            search(temp->right,ch);
        }
    }

    void display(Tnode *temp)
    {
        if(temp==NULL)
            return;

         display(temp->left);
         cout<<temp->info;
         display(temp->right);
    }

    Tnode *getposition(Tnode *root, int x)
    {  
        Tnode *temp;
        temp=root;
        while(temp&&temp->info != x)
            ((temp->info>x)?(temp=temp->left):(temp=temp->right));
        return(temp);
    }

    Tnode *getleft_right_most(Tnode *temp)
    { 
        Tnode *m=temp->left;
        while(temp->right)
            temp=temp->right;
            return temp;
    }

    Tnode *getfather(Tnode *root, Tnode *temp)
    {  
        Tnode *h=root;
        while(h->left!=temp&&h->right!=temp)
            ((h->info>temp->info)?h=h->left : h=h->right);
        return h;
    }

    Tnode *del(Tnode *temp, Tnode *f)
    {
        if(temp->left&&temp->right)
        if(temp->right)
        { 
            (f->left==temp)?f->left=temp->right : f->left=temp->right;
            temp->right=0;
        }
        if(temp->left)
        {
            (f->right==temp)?f->right=temp->left : f->right=temp->right;
            temp->left=0;
        }

        free(temp);
    }

    Tnode *delroot(Tnode *root)
    {  
        Tnode *d=root;
        if((d->right)&&!(d->left))
        { 
            root=d->right;
            d->right=0;
        }
        else if((d->left)&&!(d->right))
        { 
            root=d->left;
            d->left=0;
        }
        else
            root=0;
        return d;
    }

    Tnode *delprocess(Tnode *root, int key)
    {
        Tnode *d=root;
        Tnode *temp,*f,*t,*Re;
        if(root->info==key)
        {
            Re=delroot(d);
            return(Re);
        }
        else
        { 
            temp=getposition(d,key);
            if(temp->left!=0&&temp->right!=0)
            { 
                t=getleft_right_most(temp);
                temp->info=t->info;
                temp=t;
            }

            f=getfather(d,temp);
            Re=del(temp,f);
            return(Re);
        }
    }
};

main()
{
    tree t1;

    int ch,n,i;
    while(1)
    {
        cout <<"\n1.INSERT\n2.DELETE NUMBER\n3.DISPLAY\n4.EXIT\nEnter your                                       choice:";
        cin >> ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:   do{
                 cout <<"\nenter the elements you want to insert:";
                    cin >> ch;
                 cout<<"\nto exit insert the number -1.";
                       if(ch!=-1)
                       t1.insert(ch);
                      }while(ch!=-1);
                        break;
        case 2:   t1.display(t1.root);break;
        case 3:    cout<<"\nto delete a number of your insertion enter it : ";
                   cin>>n;
                 t1.root=t1.delprocess(t1.root,n);
                 cout<<"\nthe tree after deletion is : ";
                 t1.display(t1.root); break;
        case 4:   exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shows an error? that's all you can say? I could answer in a similar fashion: what's wrong with your program? well, it has a bug...

Answer (score 2):

There's no `<iostream.h>`. You have to use `<iostream>`. And replace `<stdlib.h>` by `<cstdlib>`.

Furthermore you're using `cout` and `cin`, which are both defined in the namespace `std`. So either use `std::cout` or `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your file, although I don't recommend the latter.

So replace your first three lines with the following ones and your program will compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

However, if you had no problem compiling your code and your error is something completely different, than you should add the concrete error message to your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bit wrong with this:

1. `#include <iostream.h>` needs to be `#include <iostream>`
2. `main()` needs to be `int main()`.
3. `tree::del` needs to return a value.
4. the switch cases in `main()` don't match the message output above the switch.
5. `tree::search` doesn't return a value if the control passes into the last `if else` block.
6. since `Tnode`s are allocated using `new`, they should be deallocated using `delete`, not `free`.
7. favour smart pointers over raw; `Tnode*` could be `std::shared_ptr<Tnode>` which would allow you to avoid calling `delete`
8. `tree` doesn't need to inherit from `Tnode`.
9. `Tnode` should be a `struct` since it has only public members and no functions.
10. meaningful variable names help understanding (e.g. is `f` short for father?)
11. generally classes shouldn't have public member variables, make class data private with public accessors.
12. prefer initialising class members in an initialisation list rather than by assignment in the constructor body
13. be consistent; e.g. stick with either `NULL` or `0`, not both (although with a C++11 compiler, definitely stick to `nullptr`)
14. disambiguate class member variables from member function parameters; you use `root` for both cases
15. care about alignment and formatting; there are a couple of places where the alignment implies you expect the control block to be greater than it is.  The general state of the formatting gives an immediate impression (in this case very accurately) of lack of care and should make any reader instantly suspicious of the logic.

And there are probably more...

Comment: +1,, in particular for \[15\]: I just tried to clean-up OP's code a little bit. I gave up after the 20th misalignment...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a small bug, you have way too many things going wrong. I suggest that you get an IDE with a debugger and step through your code to see if what happens is what you expect.

For example, in `Tnode *search` you call search recursively but you forget to use the returned value:

```
//             search(temp->left,ch);
               return search(temp->left,ch);
//             ^^^^^^
//             search(temp->right,ch);
               return search(temp->left,ch);
//             ^^^^^^
```

Another one: in `Tnode *getleft_right_most`, you probably want this instead:

```
    Tnode *m=temp->left;
//  while(temp->right)
//      temp=temp->right;
//      return temp;
    while(m->right)
        m=m->right;
        return m;
```

This is something that your compiler can help you with. Use `-Wall` (or enable all warnings) and it will point to you that you created the variable `m` and forgot to use it.

In `Tnode *del`, there is an `if` statement without a body:

```
if(temp->left&&temp->right)
if(temp->right)
```

The compiler will just take the second if statement and use it as the missing body:

```
if(temp->left&&temp->right) {
    if(temp->right)
    { // ...
    }
}
```

In `Tnode *delroot`, you probably want to

```
return root;
```

rather than `return d`. You also don't deal with the case where root has both `left` and `right` branches.

And so on, the remaining bugs are an exercise for you.

I didn't want to mention that you swapped options 2 and 3, but that was quite annoying.

A final tip: since you created a `tree` class with a `root` member, you don't need to (and you shouldn't) pass `root` as an argument to the member functions.